# Problem with double integral using Fourier transform?

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, pseudo-differential-operators

I have a doubt concearning the convergence of an integral.

Let $\mathscr{S}(\mathbb R^n)$ be the Schwartz space on $\mathbb R^n$. Given $u\in \mathscr{S}(\mathbb R^n)$ we have an well defined function:

> $$(T_af)(x):=\int_{\mathbb R^n} e^{2\pi ix\cdot \xi} a(x, \xi)\widehat{u}(\xi)\ d\xi.  $$

Indeed, this function belogs to $\mathscr{S}(\mathbb R^n)$.

Above $a\in C^\infty(\mathbb R^n\times \mathbb R^n)$ satisfies: $$|\partial^\alpha_x \partial^\beta_\xi a(x, \xi)|\leq C_{\alpha, \beta} (1+|\xi|^2)^{(m-|\beta|)/2},$$ for some constants $C_{\alpha, \beta}>0$ and some $m\in\mathbb R$ and $$\widehat{u}(\xi)=\int_{\mathbb R^n} e^{-2\pi iy\cdot \xi} u(y)\ dy,$$ is the Fourier transform of $u$.

What is the problem in rewriting $T_a$ as:

> $$(T_af)(x)=\int_{\mathbb R^n} \int_{\mathbb R^n} e^{2\pi i(x-y)\cdot
>  \xi} a(x, \xi)u(y)\ dy\ d\xi?$$

All I did was using the definition of $\widehat{u}$ in the first $T_af$ and added the two exponentials. It wasn't even needed changing integration order.

Thanks

Comment: So far, no problem. If you try to interchange the order of integration, you get a problem since $a$ isn't necessarily good enough for that to work.

Comment: However there's something wrong because the $\xi$ integral (in the second case) does not converge for arbitrary $m$.

Comment: Note that $\hat{u}\in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, so it decays fast enough for the $\xi$-integral to be defined for every $m$.

Comment: Precisely, that's what makes the first integral convergent. However, in the second we have something like $|u(y)|\leq C_N(1+|y|^2)^{-N}$ for all $N\in\mathbb N$ what makes the $y$ integral convergent. However, $|a(x, \xi)|\leq C (1+|\xi|^2)^{m}$ and we must require $m<-n$ (maybe $m<-\frac{n}{2}$) for the $\xi$ integral to converge.

Comment: As an iterated integral, as it's written, it's fine. It doesn't work (in general) if you try to interpret it as an integral over $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ (or change the order of integration).

Comment: Really interesting, this makes things clearer. Thanks =)

Comment: @DanielFischer: your last comment should perhaps be an answer.